# NuGet error while building caffe on Windows with visual studio 2013

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2013, nuget, caffe

I'm trying to build Caffe on Windows in order to use it on Python (by Import caffe) for my Deep Learning project, but I came across a problem while building the Caffe.sln file with Visual Studio 2013, following instructions from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrzAF2sxHHM (Build Caffe in 5 minutes)
I use Windows 7 64bits, here's the error message :

> 1>------ Build started: Project: libcaffe, Configuration: Release x64 ------
>
> 1>C:\Users\LU10600\Documents\DeepLearning\NugetPackages\glog.0.3.3.0\build\native\glog.targets(346,5): error : NuGet Error:Unable to find version '0.3.3.0' of package 'glog.overlay-x64_v120_Release_dynamic'.
>
> 2>------ Build started: Project: caffe, Configuration: Release x64 ------
>
> .....
>
> 15>C:\Users\LU10600\Documents\DeepLearning\NugetPackages\glog.0.3.3.0\build\native\glog.targets(346,5): error : NuGet Error:Unable to find version '0.3.3.0' of package 'glog.overlay-x64_v120_Release_dynamic'.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 15 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I do have a folder called glog.0.3.3.0 in the NugetPackages directory...So I don't why it can't find it...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on my system by overwriting the copy of NuGet.exe that was in caffe-master/windows/.nuget with the nuget.exe version that came with glog.0.3.3.0 in NugetPackages\glog.0.3.3.0\build\native\private\

Just a heads up since I was trying to follow the same tutorial; after resolving that issue I was seeing errors about missing boost libraries and it turned out that one of projects in the solution had it's boost dependency set to 61 instead of 59. I fixed that issue by changing it's nuget configuration to point to the 59 version of the lib.